# Tic tac toe: unavailable spaces keep getting overwritten

Tags: tic-tac-toe

I'm getting stuck typing my tic-tac-toe game. I've found these questions have been asked before, however as a beginner I didn't understand quite the answers, so I'll just ask again. My apologies for creating double topics!

I'm having trouble understanding why my code doesn't work. I think I have written a code that checks if a space if available, and my goal was to keep python asking for input that is in range of 1 - 10 and an available space.

Also: when I fill all the spaces with either an X or an O, the game doesn't recognise it as a tie or a win.

Please explain to me (as if I am a five year old) what I did wrong. And if you have any tips for shortening my code or improve the readability; I'm all ears. Thanks!

```
## check input from player! 

def player_position(turn):

    position = int(input("{}, please pick a position to place your marker.".format(turn)))
    
    while not (position in range(0,10)) and (position_check == True):
        position = int(input("You have to pick an available position! "))
               
    else:
        return position
```

---

```
## check if place is empty

def position_check(board,position):
    return board[position] == ' '
```

---

```
## check if there is a tie or a win

def tie_or_win(board, marker):
    
    tie_or_win = False
    
    if (board[1] == board[2] == board[3] == marker) or \
    (board[4] == board[5] == board[6] == marker) or \
    (board[7] == board[8] == board[9] == marker) or \
    (board[1] == board[5] == board[9] == marker) or \
    (board[7] == board[5] == board[3] == marker) or \
    (board[7] == board[4] == board[1] == marker) or \
    (board[8] == board[5] == board[2] == marker) or \
    (board[9] == board[6] == board[3] == marker):
        print(marker + " has won!")
        tie_or_win = True
    elif (board[1] != ' ') and \
    (board[2] != ' ') and \
    (board[3] != ' ') and \
    (board[4] != ' ') and \
    (board[5] != ' ') and \
    (board[6] != ' ') and \
    (board[7] != ' ') and \
    (board[8] != ' ') and \
    (board[9] != ' '):
        print("It's a tie!")
        tie_or_win = True
    else:
        tie_or_win = False
```

---

```
while True:
    game = True
    print("Welcome to tic-tac-toe!")
    while game == True:
        board = [' '] * 10
   
    marker1, marker2 = player_marker()
    print("Let's decide who begins!")
    print("Drumrolllllllllllll")
    turn = who_begins()
    print(input("Are you ready to play? Press any key to continue"))
    
    game_on = True
    
    while game_on:
        if turn == 'Player 1':
            display_board(board)
            turn = 'Player 1'
            position_check(board,position)
            position = player_position(turn)
            
            marker_on_board(board, position, marker1)
            tie_win = tie_or_win(board, marker1)               
            
            if tie_win == True:
                game_on = False
                break
            
            else:
                turn = 'Player 2'
         
        else:
            display_board(board)
            turn = 'Player 2'
            position_check(board,position)
            position = player_position(turn)
            marker_on_board(board, position, marker2)
            tie_win = tie_or_win(board, marker2)                
            
            if tie_win == True:
                game_on = False
                break
                
            else:
                turn = 'Player 1'
```

---

Also: when I fill all the spaces with either an X or an O, the game doesn't recognise it as a tie or a win.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the code is exactly as presented here (and that this is python, which it certainly looks like) there are two main issues that I can see:

1. When you try to check if the square is already filled, you aren't actually calling position_check, it should be something more like `position_check(board, position) == True` rather than just `position_check == True` . You may need to think about how to have the board actually available to this function
2. Your tie_or_win function doesn't return anything, and so when called will return None (which is equivalent to False). You will need to add some return statements, probably the easiest change would be something like

   ```
    def tie_or_win(board, marker):

        if (board[1] == board[2] == board[3] == marker) or \
        (board[4] == board[5] == board[6] == marker) or \
        (board[7] == board[8] == board[9] == marker) or \
        (board[1] == board[5] == board[9] == marker) or \
        (board[7] == board[5] == board[3] == marker) or \
        (board[7] == board[4] == board[1] == marker) or \
        (board[8] == board[5] == board[2] == marker) or \
        (board[9] == board[6] == board[3] == marker):
            print(marker + " has won!")
            return True
        elif (board[1] != ' ') and \
        (board[2] != ' ') and \
        (board[3] != ' ') and \
        (board[4] != ' ') and \
        (board[5] != ' ') and \
        (board[6] != ' ') and \
        (board[7] != ' ') and \
        (board[8] != ' ') and \
        (board[9] != ' '):
            print("It's a tie!")
            return True
        else:
            return False
   ```